# Delete Action fails in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to delete an entity from Index view page like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <button type="submit" value="delete" formaction="/Issue/Delete">Delete</button>
}
```

on this button click I want my DeleteConfirmed Action inside controller to happen (not go to another delete page).

Inside controller

```
  [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Issue issue = _db.Issues.Find(id);
        _db.Issues.Remove(issue);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Right now it throws an error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Int32)' in
>   'DiagnosisApp.Controllers.IssueController'. An optional parameter must
>   be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.
>
> Parameter name: parameters

Can anyone point out what is the correct approach to achieve this?

Comment: post your delete action code also.

Comment: Not related to the question but as good practice don't use hard coded urls instead make a use of @Url helpers.

Comment: You need to pass Id to your action method.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya How? Can you add a code sample?

Comment: Where does the id come from? a grid? a user input? the viewmodel? show some code plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'

tells us that you have not actually passed anything to your controller. So, to 'pass' the id value to your controller, you could use an `ActionLink` similar to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PrimaryKeyValue })
```

using your model's data within your view.

---

This 'ActionLink' will link to your CRUD scaffolding (in which I believe you're already using) within your controller;

Something like this:

```
 // GET: message/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            message message = db.messages.Find(id);
            if (message == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(message);
        }
```

which will automatically bring you to a 'delete confirmation page'. However, you might want to alter this into something like:

```
        // POST: message/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if(id !=null){
               message message = db.messages.Find(id);
               db.messages.Remove(message);
               db.SaveChanges();
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
               return HttpNotFound();
            }
        }
```

This method 'skips' the delete confirmation page, whilst still keeping validation over testing if the id isn't null. However, further validation may be required to test if the id is actually found in the db.

Which first tests if you have sent in a id value, and if so, completed the 'delete' action within your database.

**Note**

These Actions are freely available when using MVC's scaffolding

Comment: I don't want to go to delete confirmation page, that is the main issue here

Comment: @Athul: Last code snippet shows you how to skip that!

Comment: OP's problem is in POSTing the ID. Making the ID optional won't solve the problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's why at the beginning of the post, i've sent one ;P

Comment: @jbutler that's a link, not a form post. ;)

Comment: Does it not evidently work, though? Sending the id to the actionresult? @CodeCaster :P

Comment: It will work if OP removes the `[HttpPost]` attribute, but you don't want that.

Comment: It doesn't look like OP is looking to 'post' the form, only 'post' the id (of which can then be used server side). Alternatively, OP could quickly 'redirectToAction' to DeleteConfirmed ActionResult. @CodeCaster. It just depends on what OP is looking to do here, post a form or just delete from db.

Comment: You don't want to delete from database without POST. [Read about safety and idempotence](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/).

Comment: "No confirmation page" is something else than "through HTTP GET". You can still POST without confirmation.

Comment: @CodeCaster: you may be correct, however, I am going by what I personally have discovered to work, having wanted to have this functionality before. From what I have experienced so far, I have not had any issues in doing it this way.

Comment: @jbutler read [this page then](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because). Don't expose functionality that modifies resources through GET URLs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74634/discussion-between-jbutler483-and-codecaster).

Answer (score 2):

You're not providing the ID in your POST nor your URL.

Either POST to the URL containing the ID:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Controller", new { id = Model.ID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    // ...
}
```

Or POST the ID as a hidden form value:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You assume that the id is in the model... and we all know that assumption is the mother of all f*ckups.

Comment: @Paul sure, but OP is _"trying to delete an entity from Index view page"_, so while printing this form he's in a loop of some kind. Then OP can replace `Model.ID` with `currentModel.ID` or `m => m.ID` with `m => m.AllModels[i].ID` (or by using DisplayTemplates, omitting the need for a loop). And yes, that assumes the presence of an ID within one entity, which the rest of the code points to being true (`DeleteConfirmed(int id)`, `_db.Issues.Find(id)`).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It will not redirect you to delete page until you confirm it.

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "delete", "Issue", new { id = "yourId" }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" })
```

Comment: OP does not want to have a 'are you sure?' page to display at all.

Answer (score -1):

Your action state that the delete need an ID, but you didn't pass it from your view when you submit the form.

Try change your code like this.
Don't forget to change the hidden value with the ID.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<THE VALUE>"/>        
     <button type="submit" value="delete" formaction="/Issue  /Delete">Delete</button>
}
```

Comment: all these are leading me to another page on button click (delete page)

Comment: @Athul His answer is right except he needs to specify form method POST.